# How to use cash state in corda with example?

Tags: blockchain, corda

How to use cash state in Corda with example? can we use it in simple example?

Answer (score 0):

See the Obligation CorDapp sample [here](https://github.com/corda/samples).

1. The above example contains uses of the `Cash` state for `Obligation` settlement, [e.g. here](https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V3/obligation-cordapp/java-source/src/main/java/net/corda/examples/obligation/flows/SettleObligation.java#L108)
2. You can see how to issue `Cash` on `ledger` using the built-in webserver [here](https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V3/obligation-cordapp/java-source/src/main/java/net/corda/examples/obligation/ObligationApi.java#L117)